# Ruby and module inheritance

Tags: ruby, oop

This should be an easy one for a ruby dev. I'm playing around with a gem and I need help with inheriting module variables. Code should speak better than me:

```
module SomeModule
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    attr_accessor :bbonified

    class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
        initializer "some_module.study" do
            Rails.application.eager_load!
            # => I WANT TO ACCESS HERE
            puts @bbonified
        end
    end

    module ClassMethods
        def bbonify(*columns)
            # => WHAT I DEFINE HERE
            @bbonified = columns
        end
    end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, SomeModule)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to be able to access `@bbonified` directly, that's a local variable in the class that imports this module.

You need to define a separate accessor method to retrieve it:

```
module ClassMethods
  def bbonified
    @bbonified
  end
end
```

Then later you need to refer to this somehow, but as you're just talking about a module it will depend on what class has been extended.

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
SomeClass.bbonified
```